# Extract the content of a nupkg file specifically for a specified Target Framework / Target Platform

Tags: nuget, command-line-interface

Is it possible to extract the content of a nupkg file specifically for a specified Target Framework (.NET Framework, .NET Core 3.1, .NET 6, ...) / a Target Platform (32Bit / 64Bit) via the Nuget CLI?

As an example:

a) I want to have the content of the *.nupkg file I need if I have a 32bit .NET Framework 4.72 project.

b) I want to have the content of the *.nupkg file I need if I have a 64Bit .NET Core 3.1 project

I know I could accomplish this via Visual Studio if I build an appropriate project, but I need the content without dependent nuget files. But if there is a way to achieve that via Visual Studio, that would be great too.

I also know that the nupkg files are just ZIP files, but I don't want to parse the package itself and determine which binaries I need for a specific Target Frame / Target Platform combination.